# Python SMTPException, using bottle-cork Bottle plugin

Tags: python, smtp, bottle

I'm creating a website. Its backend is powered by Bottle framework.
I tried to use Bottle-Cork plugin, but got `SMTPException` error.

I run the sample code of Bottle-Cork source - [simple_webapp.py](https://github.com/FedericoCeratto/bottle-cork/blob/master/examples/simple_webapp.py) with Python 2.

I modified 21st line of the example file like this:

```py
aaa = Cork('example_conf', email_sender='fsomeone@somewhere.com', smtp_url='smtp://username:password@192.168.3.2:25')
```

The error output is:

```sh
python simple_webapp.py 
Bottle v0.12.18 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

localhost - - [2019-12-30 23:43:48,401] Sending email using 192.168.3.2
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2019 23:43:48] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 200 26
localhost - - [2019-12-30 23:43:48,424] Performing login
localhost - - [2019-12-30 23:43:48,426] Error sending email: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ggomee/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cork/cork.py", line 968, in _send
    session.login(self._conf['user'], self._conf['pass'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 586, in login
    raise SMTPException("SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

On the server side, I installed Postfix server and the error output is:

```sh
Dec 30 23:43:48 arete postfix/smtpd[1284]: connect from unknown[192.168.3.26]
Dec 30 23:43:48 arete postfix/smtpd[1284]: lost connection after EHLO from unknown[192.168.3.26]
Dec 30 23:43:48 arete postfix/smtpd[1284]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.3.26] ehlo=1 commands=1
```

I found many similar questions here(StackOverflow), but they all answered to fix code manually. According to them, should I fix Bottle-Cork plugin manually?

I think this error is caused by wrong setting of mail server. Anyway, help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I skipped some Postfix setting steps.

Following [Postfix SMTP Auth doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/postfix.html#postfix-smtp-authentication) step-by-step, I could finally send email to my account.
But as I'm new to SMTP and server configuration, I'm waiting more detailed answers and comments.

Of course it was treated as a spam mail by web mail clients.